# combine/merge two columns into 1 ( t-sql )

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union, coalesce

I have 2 tables: `batters` and `pitchers`

I want to pull

```
playerid(nvarchar50), firstname(nvarchar50), lastname(nvarchar50), bats(nvarchar50)
```

from the `batters` table

and

```
playerid(nvarchar50), firstname(nvarchar50), lastname(nvarchar50), throws(nvarchar50)
```

from the `pitchers` table

I want to combine the output so that when i get results it comes out like this

```
playerid, firstname, lastname, throws, bats
```

Is this possible? I'm guessing it should be but I've exhausted joins and unions and cant get the result set to come out that way. Remember they are two different tables

**bat** table

```
playerID    nameFirst   nameLast    bats
----------------------------------------
abreubo01   Bobby       Abreu       L
abreujo02   Jose        Abreu       R
abreuto01   Tony        Abreu       B
ackledu01   Dustin      Ackley      L
adamecr01   Cristhian   Adames      S
adamsla01   Lane        Adams       R
adamsma01   Matt        Adams       L
```

**pit** table

```
playerid    nameFirst   nameLast    throws
------------------------------------------
abadfe01    Fernando    Abad        L
aceveal01   Alfredo     Aceves      R
achteaj01   A.J.        Achter      R
adamsau01   Austin      Adams       R
adamsmi03   Mike        Adams       R
adcocna01   Nathan      Adcock      R
affelje01   Jeremy      Affeldt     L
```

Desired Result

**pit** table

```
playerid    nameFirst   nameLast    throws  Bats
------------------------------------------------
abadfe01    Fernando    Abad              
aceveal01   Alfredo     Aceves              
achteaj01   A.J.        Achter             
adamsau01   Austin      Adams       
adamsmi03   Mike        Adams      
adcocna01   Nathan      Adcock     
affelje01   Jeremy      Affeldt
```

Comment: So what do you have so far? Do all players bat and pitch (seems impossible), they must or are you getting batting records for pitchers?

Comment: are you saying the same playerid appears in both tables? If so why don't you just have one "players" table with playerid, firstname, lastname, throws, bats. Then you're not duplicating data (e.g. names and IDs) and you don't have to worry about how to combine them. Even if that's not how the data is structured, it might still be simpler to have one players table. You can always have an extra "player type" column to denote if they're a batter or pitcher (or can some people be both??)

Comment: thanks guys for your response. I am moreso doing this to get better at sql. Anyways, I received 2 tables, one is pitcher one is batters. I want to join them but have only 1 playerid column. Im just playing around with data.

Comment: Ok thanks but unfortunately your comment hasn't entirely answered my questions. To help us, please give examples of the rows of data stored in each of the tables, and then an example of what the desired query output would look like, based on those rows of data. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. I came back to your question by chance...but if you want us to see your updates in future, please tag someone in your comment by using @ and then typing their username, and then select it from the little popup. Otherwise there is a good chance we will never return to the question to help you. Cheers.

Comment: @ADyson 
HEy guys updated the question with the data types. Please help if you can. Thanks for the tip ADyson

Comment: ok that's a good start but it's still a long way from what I asked you to provide...read my comments again - specifically we need sample data and expected results, as I mentioned. We'll find it very hard to help until you give all the necessary info. Thanks.

Comment: @stupid_idiot If you have control of your data schema, change the bats and throws data types to integers.

Comment: @WorkSmarter thanks im not trying to recreate the schema because im trying to get better at t-sql by putting myself in positions where im forced to right join queries and the such.  i want to make a practice of it. I updated my original post with data structure.

Comment: @ADyson thanks I tried to update it to provide better clarification.

Comment: And what about expected result? Is it just all of them listed together? Or is there any combining - e.g. can the same player ever appear in both tables, or not? P.S. I formatted it so we can actually read the data properly. There's a page in the help showing you how to use the editing tools to make your question legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

1) You just want a list of all the players without any restrictions

2) The same player ID never appears in both tables (or if it does, you don't care if they're listed twice)

Based on those assumptions, you can simply write:

```
SELECT playerID, nameFirst, nameLast, bats, NULL as throws
FROM bats
UNION ALL
SELECT playerID, nameFirst, nameLast, NULL as bats, throws
FROM pits
```

---

However, I think your data is not fully normalised. Both of these tables are actually lists of players, just with a slight variation in their attributes. So a more sensible overall approach would be simply to have a single "players" table with columns as follows:

```
playerID, nameFirst, nameLast, bats, throws
```

Bats and throws would both be nullable, in case the player doesn't do that action. If necessary you could add an extra "player_type" column to denote their role (batter, pitcher - or both, if that's allowed).

Once you've got that structure, the query is trivial:

```
SELECT playerID, nameFirst, nameLast, bats, throws
FROM players
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it! I'm just trying to get better at querying so I'm downloading spreadsheets of sports data across the web and trying to learn sql by putting together queries to populate data. From here I would try and get the results per team and stuff like that.